# How to implement a fragmented config file validation in go

Tags: go

I try to configure a CLI app via config file (yaml). The app has several "components" (lets say a persistence layer, an integrated web server etc.). Those components are managed in subpackages to keep the code tidy. The configuration of those components is defined inside their packages
and "merged" in a config package to a struct that represents the config file. See this code as a demo implementation:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

//
// This would be in package 'webserver'
// Only the Config part is shown, there would be a constructor and the implementation of
// the webserver as well...
//

// WebserverConfig holds all required configuration params
type WebserverConfig struct {
    Listen    string `yaml:"listen"`
    Autostart bool   `yaml:"autostart"`
}

// Validate checks if all fields make sense and returns a list of error string if problems
// are found
func (wsc WebserverConfig) Validate() (error, []string) {
    errs := []string{}
    if wsc.Listen == "" {
        errs = append(errs, "Field 'listen' must not be empty.")
    }
    if len(errs) > 0 {
        err := errors.New("Config of 'webserver' has errors")
        return err, errs
    }
    return nil, errs
}

// UnmarshalYAML implements a custom unmarshaller to make sure defaults are set
// to meaningful values
func (wsc *WebserverConfig) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    type WebserverConfigDefaulted WebserverConfig
    var defaults = WebserverConfigDefaulted{
        Listen:    ":8080",
        Autostart: true,
    }

    out := defaults
    err := unmarshal(&out)
    *wsc = WebserverConfig(out)
    return err
}

//
// This would be in package conf
//
//

// Config is the global configuration composed of all component configuration sections
type Config struct {
    Webserver WebserverConfig `yaml:"webserver"`
}

// Load reads the bytes into the global config
func Load(data string) (Config, error) {
    c := Config{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &c)
    if err != nil {
        return c, fmt.Errorf("Error while unmarshalling configuration from yaml: %s", err.Error())
    }
    return c, nil
}

// Validate should call each individual component configurations validate function (if it exists)
func (c Config) Validate() error {
    // TODO: IMPLEMPNT...
    return nil
}

//
// This is finally in main
//
//

var yamlFile = `---
webserver:
  listen: ":9999" 
`

func main() {
    c, err := Load(yamlFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    err = c.Validate()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Find it on the playground here (does not run because of the dep to yaml): https://play.golang.org/p/i3EAZJP7aYz

QUESTION: At this point I have no idea how the global validation function `func (c Config) Validate() error` could be implemented to call all Validate funcs of the 'component configurations' (such as `func (wsc WebserverConfig) Validate() (error, []string)`). Any idea or hints?

Comment: Could `c.Validate()` call `c.Webserver.Validate()`? It seems like it, since `Validate` is called after `Load`. If so, it might help to define a Validater interface to reduce code duplication if the `Config` type has many elements. If you don't want to update the list of things to `Validate`, you would have to use reflection to get all of the elements of the `Config` type.

Comment: @TylerBui-Palsulich You are right and I was overthinking the problem: My first attempt was based on a Validater interface. Also the component configs registerd itself to the global config, therefore changes to the global config where obsolete for new configs. The problem with is to unmarshal into an interface - I could not find a neat way to do so. My current implementation iterated over the struct fields via reflection which is not nice. Hardcode `c.Webserver.Validate()` into `c.Validate()` is simple, readable and explicit - and obvious. Sorry for that stupid question.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped. Not a stupid question at all. I hadn't thought about this type of config idea before. I added an answer based on these comments to make sure the question doesn't show up as unanswered when others are searching/doing triage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend calling `c.Webserver.Validate()` from `c.Validate()`.

The downside of this is you need to update `c.Validate()` every time you add a new config, which might be easy to forget. However, it is "simple, readable and explicit" (quoting from your comment).

Alternatively, you could loop over every element of the config to see which ones match a `Validater` interface then call `Validate` on them. But, this would be much more complicated and more difficult to understand & debug. The usual recommendation is to avoid reflection unless absolutely necessary.